# How to customise the Admin panel in Keystone JS? (Or: how do the custom admin pages in Keystone JS demo-project/blog work?)

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, keystonejs, headless-cms

We are looking to use KeystoneJS in a large project and we want to be able to customise the Admin panel.  There's a nice example of how to do it [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/demo-projects/blog), and I've been reviewing this [PR to the project](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/1019/files).  Although the example looks as if it would work for us, I don't understand the logic behind it, that is, what we would need to implement to make it work, what the possibilities and constraints are.

Is it the case that when you use the Keystone NextJS app (which is good for us), if you add a folder `/admin/pages` the Keystone app will look there and use those custom admin pages instead of the regular ones?  I'm assuming we have full access to the rest of the app, the controllers, the DB from these pages as well....

I also noticed that JedWatson notes in https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/1019 that

> Note this lacks SSR support, and I didn't put as much effort into the examples, but it's otherwise (I think) identical in functionality.

Does it lack SSR support just for the admin part, or does adding custom admin pages somehow affect SSR support in the rest of the app? (SSR is the reason we're using next)

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two api for custom pages, one is `pages` option in the `admin-ui` app constructor and 2nd is part of `hooks` api in keystone constructor.

1. `pages`: this one is legacy and only adds custom pages, it does not overwrite the existing list pages in admin-ui it only hides them if not properly configured. usually the `Dashboard` is visible and all lists are listed there.
2. `hooks`: this is new and expected to add more customization options, unfortunately my PRs are stale and they are not the spec keystone core team would want to add. this also does not removes any pages.

admin ui runs as react app built or loaded using webpack config. that is why there is no ssr support. even though the example use a custom admin directory but that not loaded by `nextjs` component, it is loaded dynamically using webpack server mounting the admin-ui react app

if you really want to have ssr, you can use some learning from closed PRs which were used as POC long ago. but that would be overkill as the admin-ui has many more updates after that.

hooks/pages have access to core limited set of access, there are some access based on React context, provider and consumer hooks. You can use react-apollo hooks as there is already provider wrapped at root of react context. you can also make use of react router hooks, they are upgraded to latest version. it has no access to server side context or controller. (not sure what you meant by controller)

Comment: Do you know when the 'hooks' version of custom admin pages will be ready?  We are thinking of using the 'pages' version (for now at least), since it seems to be stable.  But we are having trouble deciphering what's going on in https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/demo-projects/blog/admin/index.js  That is, why are some `children` referencing existing lists with `listKey: 'PostCategory'`, and others (`People` in the example) with `children: ['User']`?  What exactly do we need to know to build the pages?

Comment: hooks version is ready, you can use it now. things you mentioned are two different ways to put things in the config, if you do not want to change any label of the list, you just use array of string in children, when you need to change the label like Category instead of list name PostCategory, you use the alternate way.,

Comment: Where is the documentation for the hooks version of the custom admin page?  I see docs for the lifecycle hooks, but this is something else...

Comment: poor documentation, this was in PR here - https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/1927

Comment: I looked at the PR you sent, but it says "This creates a framework for Admin hooks and Custom Actions.

It doesn't set-up any hooks at the moment except converting the current custom pages mechanism over to using this while retaining compatibility with the old API." -- 

Are the hooks actually doing anything at the moment?

Comment: nothing much, I have two PRs if they decide on specs hooks will be really useful. https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/2155 and https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/2156

it is very slow when it cones to spec out new thing not initiated by core team.